# Measure shortest distance around polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

How do I measure the shortest distance between two points (1 and 2) with respect to a polygon? So the shortest way around the polygon from 1 to 2.

[image]

Comment: Isn´t the shortest path simply along the convex hull of the polygon?

Comment: No, then it would follow the contours of the polygon.

Comment: ***Convex*** hull would skip the concave parts.

Comment: So that would be the shortest distance? How does it work?

Comment: Convex hulls will have issues in some instances, such as the one above, where the end point is inside a concave location. `Least cost path` would be the easiest way to go with this I believe, but that requires the spatial analyst extension.

Comment: I have the spatial analyst extension. Thank you will try this!

Answer (score 1):

Using the [convex-hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of a polygon this is quite easy. First you have to include your two points in the set of points building the polygon. Now build the convex-hull for that point-cloud which is always the shortest path around the polygon.

There is a GP-tool at Data Management called [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000.htm) which you may use for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am pretty new in ArcGis, do you know of any guides who explain how to do this?

Comment: The answer has a link to the tool documentation.  Teaching ArcGIS use should not be part of the answer.